# Problema con Binding en Blazor

Tags: c#, binding, blazor

he intentado esto:
`

```
   <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm Model="@this" >
        <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputCheckbox @bind-Value="Value"  style="display:inline" />
    </Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm>
@code{
    bool value;
    [Parameter]
    public bool Value { get => value; set => this.value = value; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> ValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

`

y no se porque no va...osea el control funciona pero el binding no...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Te falta implementar la llamada para el eventos de actualizacion de variable.
Implementando el siguiente codigo te tendira que funcionar:

```
    <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm Model="@this">
    <Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.InputCheckbox @bind-Value="Value" style="display:inline"  @oninput="OnValueChanged"  />
</Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm>

<p>@value.ToString()</p>
@code{
    bool value;
    [Parameter]
    public bool Value { get => value; set => this.value = value; }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    private Task OnValueChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Value = (bool)e.Value;

        return ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias :)

Comment: Aún que esta solución funciona, no estais utilizando el binding para actualizar la variable "Value".

Answer (score 1):

En el Blazor sistema de binding puede ser one-way o two-way. En el caso que queremos tener doble direccionamiento en el binding, hay que utilizar @bind="Variable", en caso que control no implementa un evento por defecto, hay que indicar 2 cosas - variable que vamos utilizar en binding y que evento tiene que producirse, para que nosotros capturamos el cambio de la variable de forma automatica, sin tener que procesar lo (como esta descrito en la respuesta del Hazuky).

Solución basada en el codigo presentado, pero con el uso del sistema de binding real:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms

<EditForm Model="this">
    <InputCheckbox @bind-Value="Value" @bind-Value:event="ValueChanged" style="display:inline" />
</EditForm>

@code{
    bool value = false;

    [Parameter]
    public bool Value
    {
        get => this.value;
        set
        {
            if (this.value == value) return;
            this.value = value;
            ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(this.value);
        }
    }
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> ValueChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Como podeis observar, aparte de indicar `@bind-Value="Value"`, ademas tenemos que indicar que evento produce el cambio con `@bind-Value:event="ValueChanged"`.

Es obvio que podeis no saber cual evento produce el cambio, para ello podeis mirar el codigo fuente del componente y de alli saber que eventos tiene. En el caso del  [InputCheckbox.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputCheckbox.cs) no lo vais a ver, ya que no tiene eventos propios, los hereda de la clase [InputBase.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputBase.cs), en la cual podeis ver que el evento se llama "ValueChanged" en la linea 45 del codigo fuente. Asi que para capturar el cambio de la variable utilizando el sistema de binding, tenemos que utilizar este nombre. Y con esto seria suficiente.

Si ademas queremos elevar este cambio a nivel superior, lo que podemos hacer para que queda bien limpio el codigo, es llamar en su setter al evento, que nos elevara el cambio al componente superior utilizando `ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(this.value);`.

Tambien como buena practica se añade `if (this.value == value) return;` en el setter, de esta manera si el valor no cambia, no deberia reasignar la variable y no deberia saltar el evento sobre el cambio del valor, ya que no se cambio.

Tambien yo personalmente aconsejo utilizar los using's, para tener el codigo mas facil de leer, tal como lo pongo en el ejemplo con el uso de `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms`.